# Form loaded via ajax wont append data to parent window

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am basically creating a Restaurant Menu editor for their website. The issue I am having is when the click a category named Brunch, I load the file edit_cat.php via ajax onto the page. All data is passed correctly, but on success of the form being filled out I would like to post a success message on the parent window and am having no luck. Coincidentally, upon success the alert(data) does popup with the response.

> edit_cat.php both handles the form submission and is the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.editBtn').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this),
                    id = $this.data('id'),
                    type = $this.data('type');
                    if (type == 'cat') {
                        data = "&cat=" + id;
                        $.ajax({
                            data: data,
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'edit_cat.php',
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('#contentLeft').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
            });

            $('#contentLeft').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this),
                    frm = $('#edit-cat-frm'),
                    id = $('form').data('id'),
                    name = $(frm).find('input[name="name"]').val(),
                    desc = $(frm).find('textarea[name="desc"]').val(),
                    send = $(frm).find('input[name="submit"]').val();
                    data = "&cat=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&desc=" + desc + "&submit=" + send;
                    $.ajax({
                        data: data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'edit_cat.php',
                        success: function(data) {
                                window.parent.$('.left-container-head').innerHtml(data);
                        }
                    });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this as simply,

```
$('.left-container-head').html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".left-container-head", window.parent.document).html(data);
```

Comment: I updated the answer. If we use `jQuery` then of course it's `.html()`

Comment: check the console, maybe there's a frame access error

Comment: no errors whatsoever. whats awkward is that the alert works just fine.

Comment: what if you try `$(window)` or `$(window.top)` ?

Comment: nothing. ive tried all that & i cant find anything regarding this issue. only fix i find is using an iframe which i want to avoid completely

Comment: $('#error').html(data); it was as easy as that. for some odd reason it was working earlier. thanks for ur help.